# Prevent UIScrollView scrolling if slide gesture is in a rea

Tags: ios, objective-c, c

I have a `UIScrollView` and a subview of that view is a `UISlider`. I am finding that when I try to slide the `UISlider` the `UIScrollView` scrolls.

Can I make it so the scroll view only slides if I am not touching the `UISlider`?

Answer (score 2):

You could use this `self.slider.exclusiveTouch = YES;`

From the Apple Documentation:

> Restrict event delivery to a single view. By default, a view’s exclusiveTouch property is set to NO, which means that one view does not block other views in a window from receiving touches. If you set the property to YES for a specific view, then that view receives touches if—and only if—it is the only view tracking touches.

So by setting your slider's `exclusiveTouch` property, you can prevent `scrollView` from receiving the touches and therefore it will not slide.